# Starting solution in CPLEX Optimization Studio

Tags: optimization, cplex

I am solving a MIP in IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio. I would like to first generate a solution where the main decision variables need not be integers, which will then be used as a starting solution to solve the model where the decision variables should be integers.

What should I type in my .mod file to obtain this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please note that this site is not a code writing service. If you
[edit] your question to describe what you have tried so far and where
you are stuck, then we can try to help with specific problems. You
should also read [ask].

Comment: As far as I understand you want to solve LP relaxation and then used it as a warm start. Cplex will do it for you, so just formulate your MIP and throw it to Cplex.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use a main() function to control the sequence of solves. This can be done either all in one .mod file or with the main() in a separate .mod file that controls the process of using/solving the others. This is described in the documentation. There are examples in the OPL samples folder; see mulprod or LangrangianRelaxation. Give it a go, and when you have something concrete that doesn't work, come back and ask again.